# How can I pass the value of task id in this example to Chakra UI modal to update the task title?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am learning to build a to-do app in Nextjs + Typescript. I have a Chakra UI modal which pops up when the user clicks on the "edit task" button. The modal contains a Input element and it should have the value of task title. Here is the solution that I have implemented.

```
//  components/tasks.tsx

import { Box } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import Task from '../components/task';
import EditTaskModal from '../components/edit-task-modal';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useModalContext } from '../store/modal';

const Tasks: NextPage = () => {
  const { onOpen } = useModalContext();

  const [editTaskID, setEditTaskID] = useState('');
  const handleOpenModal = (id: string) => {
    setEditTaskID(id);
    onOpen();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <EditTaskModal id={editTaskID} />
      <Box>
        <Task handleOpenModal={handleOpenModal} />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tasks;
```

```
//  components/task.tsx

import { NextPage } from 'next';
import { Box, Checkbox, Button, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useTaskContext } from '../store/tasks';
import { useModalContext } from '../store/modal';

type TaskProps = {
  handleOpenModal: (id: string) => void;
};

const Task: NextPage<TaskProps> = ({ handleOpenModal }) => {
  const { tasks } = useTaskContext();
  const { onOpen } = useModalContext();
  return (
    <Box>
      {tasks.map((task) => {
        return (
          <Box
            key={task.id}
            border="3px solid"
            borderColor="gray.200"
            marginBottom="1em"
            p="1em"
            borderRadius="5px"
            display="flex"
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="space-between"
          >
            <Text key={task.id}>{task.title}</Text>
            <Box width="35%" display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
              <Button
                size="sm"
                onClick={() => {
                  handleOpenModal(task.id);
                }}
              >
                Edit
              </Button>
              <Button size="sm" colorScheme="red">
                Delete
              </Button>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        );
      })}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

```
//  components/edit-task-modal.tsx
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalOverlay,
  ModalContent,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalCloseButton,
  ModalBody,
  FormControl,
  Input,
  ModalFooter,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useModalContext } from '../store/modal';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useTaskContext } from '../store/tasks';

type EditTaskModalProps = {
  id: string;
};

type updateTaskType = { id: string; title: string; status: boolean };

const updateTask = async (task: updateTaskType) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/tasks', {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(task),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const EditTaskModal: NextPage<EditTaskModalProps> = ({ id }) => {
  const { tasks } = useTaskContext();
  const task = tasks.find((task) => {
    return task.id === id;
  });
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(task?.title);

  const { isOpen, onClose } = useModalContext();
  return (
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
      <ModalOverlay />
      <ModalContent>
        <ModalHeader>Update Task Name</ModalHeader>
        <ModalCloseButton />
        <ModalBody pb={6}>
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              placeholder="Task Name"
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setTitle(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </FormControl>
        </ModalBody>

        <ModalFooter>
          <Button
            colorScheme="blue"
            mr={3}
            onClick={() => {
              if (task !== undefined)
                updateTask({
                  title: task.title,
                  status: task.status,
                  id: task.id,
                });
            }}
          >
            Update
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={onClose}>Cancel</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </ModalContent>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default EditTaskModal;
```

```
//  store/modal.tsx
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { useDisclosure } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const ModalContext = createContext<any>(null);

const ModalProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const { onOpen, onClose, isOpen } = useDisclosure();
  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={{ onOpen, onClose, isOpen }}>
      {children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useModalContext = () => {
  return useContext(ModalContext);
};

export { ModalProvider, useModalContext };
```

However, I noticed that the value attribute in Input element is always one state update behind for some reason and I can't figure out why. Is there a better solution to pass task id to the modal?